# Messaging Protocol

Tags: c++, message, protocols

How should I design my message protocol so that I distinguish between user data and termination of the message.

For example I take input from user to send it to client over TCP/IP, now the client-side needs to know the length of message, what I thought that I use some kind of termination by which the client recognizes that message end has been reached?

How do I something like this in C++. I'm using Windows sockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonably common strategy for application-specific protocols is, instead of using termination, to encode message length before the message.  So the first few bytes (how many varies) specify the message length, and some special code (usually all bits on or all bits off) designates an overlong message that requires continuation.

**Edit:** An example has been requested.  Let's say we've designed our protocol so that the maximum size of a message is 255 bytes, and we want to send the string "hi".  Our protocol message will consist of three bytes: `2`, `104`, `105`.  The first byte, `2`, tells us the length of the message that follows it.  The second and third bytes, `104` and `105`, are ASCII for `h` and `i`.

Comment: How? Please give an example, as I'm unable to easily understand without examples :)

Comment: looks like a do it for me type question

Comment: - Don't forget a scheme for messages longer than 255, even if you don't need it now (or ever) at least don't design messages that would make adding this later difficult.

- Also don't forget to protect against lying messages. For example, I send a message of length 10, but only send 5. Do you lock-up (bad)? Can you detect this? Drop the connection? Try to recover?

- WATCH YOUR BUFFERS! Don't overrun them! (classic security flaw)

Answer (score 1):

You could transmit length first, then the message.

Comment: How? Can you provide an example?

Comment: The sender side writes the number of bytes in the message payload into the wire, then the message payload. The receiver side reads the number of bytes, then it knows the length of the payload and reads the payload.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the message in chunks and prepend each chunk with its length. The stream would be terminated by a chunk of zero length. (This is the way HTTP does it if the stream length isn't known in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many computer systems that use special markers to determine the end of a message - c uses \0 on character arrays, JPEG uses 0xFF as a marker, and such.

All these systems lead us to the conclusion that prefixing messages with their length is far more straightforward and robust.

TCP itself actually does this.  If you write two bytes of user input to a socket, there will be two bytes available at the other end, and the TCP packets being handled by the system know this because they mark each packet with its payload length.

Once you've done sending input, you can [shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740481(VS.85).aspx) the socket from one side and the other side will be notified (if they've enabled such notifications).

Comment: How to prefix messages with length? What if the length is not send fully the first time?

Comment: Always keep on reading until the complete message is read.  So firstly, keep on reading until you have x bytes (lenghth), then keep reading until the all bytes according to the length are received.

Comment: a protocol means a set of rules known by sender and receiver.  You start with a header which at least has a length-field of x bytes.  The receiver must know the used header.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could follow the example of POP and use a "." at the beginning of an empty line.