# Send string with multiple numbers Client/Server TCP

Tags: c, tcp, server, client

i am working on a TCP client/server communication in C. Client has to get the number of data(not > 6), get the data and send them to server in a single string message like this: 4 11 21 9 11.
4 is the number of data and 11, 21, 9, 11 are data.

Then, server has to read message, print it and send to client the number of data received(4).

I tried this for client:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus= 0;
    char buffsend[256];
    char buffrecv[256];
    int n, i;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (3 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    /* create a streaming socket      */
    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for connecting */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use the IP address sent as an argument for the server address  */
    //bzero(&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer));
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //inet_addr(argv[2], &simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  connect to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }





    /* get the message from the server   */



      do {

        printf("get numb of data or terminate(write '0'): ");
        fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
        n=atoi(buffsend);
        if(n>6) {
          printf("Error\n");

         }
        else {
                for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                   printf("insert number: ");
                   fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
                   write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend)+1);


         }



     } while((n!=0) && (n>0));





    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

And this for server:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    char buff[256];
    char message[256];
    int count;

    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (2 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for listening */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use INADDR_ANY to bind to all local addresses  */
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  bind to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer,sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* lets listen on the socket for connections      */
    returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

    if (returnStatus == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen on socket!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)

    {

        struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
    int simpleChildSocket = 0;
    int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

    /* wait here */

        simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

    if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);

    }

        /* handle the new connection request  */
    /* write out our message to the client */


        while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256))
            cont++;
            printf("%s", buff);
        printf("Data received: %d %s\n", cont, buff);



       close(simpleChildSocket);
    }

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: And in what way does it malfunction?

Comment: Server only receives one number at a time and not the whole string of data

Comment: I can see that the send string is overwritten with each input, so the server only gets the last input.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. How can i avoid overwriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the client is sending a string terminator (`\0`) after each value, so when the server prints the entire message it stops printing after the first value.

This particular problem can be overcome by not including the string terminator when sending:

```
      write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend)); /* Removed the +1 */
```

You need to add a string terminator when receiving the message:

```
    int length;
    char buff[256];

    while((length = read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256-1)) > 0) {
        buff[length] = `\0`;
        cont++;
        printf("Data received: %d %d %s\n", cont, length, buff);
    }
```

Also note that you are using stream-based sockets. That means that the sockets themselves have no concept of a message protocol. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333109/messaging-protocol) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't compile your client for testing. I use **netcat** for my test (netcat 0 port)

I didn't understand what was the problem, is it because you don't have the print ? 
That's because **printf** use **puts**, and **puts** do some buffering, so your print are displayed whenever the client is shutdown (and the **clientFd** is closed)

If it's because you have undefined behavior, here are some advices :

1 : do not forget the '\0' in your buff

2 : Avoid static allocation (buff[256]), use **getline** function instead. You get a malloced line (and trust me, playing with the stack can give you lots of undefined behavior (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))

3 : Lot's of Conditional jump running with *valgrind*

else, the communication system seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256))
        cont++;
        printf("%s", buff);
```

This can't work. You call `read` as if it understood your message format and return a C-style string corresponding to a message. But it can't do that because it has no idea what your messages are like.

You need to store the return value of `read` so that you know how many bytes you read and put it into a buffer to determine whether or not it's a message. If you want to treat it like a C-style string, you have to make it follow the rules for a C-style string.

```
               write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend)+1);
```

This is kind of puzzling too. By adding one to the length of the string, you are sending the zero byte. But your description of your messages didn't say anyhing about a zero byte. If your messages are terminated by a zero byte, then your "receive a message" code has to look for zero bytes to find the terminators so it knows where a message ends. You have no code to do that either.

So, go back a bit. Precisely define your message format. Does it include zero bytes? Or how do you find the end of a message? If you read "2 1 3" is that a full message? How do you know it's not "2 1 37" and the `7` didn't arrive yet?

Once you work out your message format and understand how it's supposed to work, write code to receive a message.